# Java notnoop,APNS No trusted certificate found from inside tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, certificate, apple-push-notifications

We have implemented APNS connectivity using notnoop. We have been testing it for last 5 months on development and UAT environment and other environment. Things were working as expected but post deployment to production environment we are having tough time getting it work, GCM is working fine it is only APNS were we have tough time.

Initially there was connectivity issue from firewall which we have got opened to connect to `gateway.push.apple.com` on `2195` as earlier system was throwing `connection timeout`.

Now system is throwing `No Trusted Certificate found` I have described below the detail steps we have already taken to debug this.

Please note this is happening only when i deploy it on production that too when it is run inside Tomcat 8.0. We did small POC to test if it can work outside tomcat and it is working properly using same certificate from same absolute path.

- We did try after changing the implementation to use absolute path of certificate as shown below

  `APNS.newService().withCert(PRODcertificatePath, PRODcertificatePassword)`

The program is configured to use `.withProductionDestination()` if it is using production certificate and vice versa so this issue is also taken care.

- Then we also tried using ClassLoader `InputStream iss = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Axis-APNS.p12")`

Yes we do have JKS file on production whose detail is configured in *server.xml*  something like below

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/root/cert"
```

Now we are out of idea to debug and find the root cause, Any suggestion, question is most welcome.

Comment: Add the full error trace to see the details

Comment: As of now system is printing this much information but will print complete stack trace. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Comment: As a matter of workaround, i have redesign my system. Instead of running from inside tomcat, Have made it as standalone application using Quartz  batch job and system is running properly. Once i get time to find out why tomcat is not able to pick correct certificate, will upate you guys on it. Thank you very much for your time... email me if you need anymore help on above matter. Thanks, Amarjeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of workaround, i have redesign my system. Instead of running from inside tomcat, Have made it as standalone application using Quartz  batch job and system is running properly. Once i get time to find out why tomcat is not able to pick correct certificate, will upate you guys on it. Thank you very much for your time... email me if you need anymore help on above matter. 
Thanks, 
Amarjeet